# Dequeue scripts and styles on login page

Tags: wordpress, authentication, conditional-statements

I am trying to find a way to dequeue styles and scripts on the  "login, password reset and register " default wp pages.

I understand there is 'login_enqueue_scripts' but no such thing as login_dequeue_scripts.

Whats your approach  ? Ive tried something like this:

````
add_filter('body_class', function($classes) {
        if (in_array('login', $classes)) {
            wp_dequeue_style( 'list-css' );
            wp_dequeue_style( 'blog-css' );
            wp_dequeue_style( 'dir-css' );
            wp_dequeue_style( 'author-css' );
        }
        return $classes;
        });```
````

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the wp_dequeue_script/style function for the login_enqueue_script action.  Like so:

```
function custom_login_page() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'list-css');
}

add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_login_page' );
```

The action of 'login_enqueue_scripts' is what happens when the other scripts/styles are loaded on that page.  You can create a custom function to run when that happens, which is what you want.

However, rather than dequeueing, why not just write some of your own CSS for the elements on the page, then enqueue whatever that custom CSS?

```
function custom_login_css() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-login-styles', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/custom-login.css' );
}

add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_login_css' );
```

Here's a [good reference for the different elements](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/customize-login-page/) you can customize with CSS on the WP login page.